# In R Shiny with reactable package how to make table downloadable by clicking on download font-awsome icon?

Tags: r, shiny, reactable, reactablefmtr

This is my code:

```r
library(shiny)
    
ui <- fluidPage(
      
data<- iris[1,] %>% mutate(download = 1),
      
reactable(data,
    columns = list(
      download = colDef(cell = icon_assign(data, icon = "download"))))
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I make this table downloadable by clicking on the `download` icon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have some stuff in your server function. Below is a template you can take from. Main takeaways: download button in ui, add server info for the download button

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("table")

    )

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}
```